# How to target the accordion panel-header when it clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I've an accordion which contain large copy as panel body. When I open any accordion, it goes to the top and copy seems cut off. Is there any fix to solve this or need to target the panel-header while open accordion?

Here's a [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilpaul/gjev2xm2/6/) to see how it looks.

[image]

Looking forward to see any replies,

Paul

Comment: @makshh see the image when we clicked 'From 70's' the title/header goes upwards and we can't see that in the view area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered similar question but it was for [materialize.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622986/materialize-collapsible-with-a-huge-content-does-not-scroll-to-top-of-the-tab/37761413#37761413).

You may tweak my logic tho, cause this one is biased by my style. And to make it the same as my previous answer, I'd like to also state it that the scrolling effect is NOT applied if

- It's the first panel element between the accordion,
- Its body has lower height than desired height

---

This applies the scrolling effect once the panel body is "shown" (post-animation) by listening on bootstrap's collapse `shown.bs.collapse` event, so I can do my validation whether the height is greater than my desired height.

```
$('.panel-collapse').each(function(){
    $(this).on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            //$header = $this.siblings('.panel-heading'),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            height = $this.height(),
            maxHeight = 400;

        if ($parent.is(':first-child')) return;

        if (height > maxHeight)
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $parent.offset().top
            }, 500);
    });
})
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjev2xm2/7/)

---

According to comment, of course previous snippet doesn't scroll up to header once the height isn't greater than my chosen max height. (I've lowered it to 400, see above snippet)

In case you wanna remove validation I made, then remove all the `if` parts and here we go.

```
$('.panel-collapse').each(function(){
    $(this).on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),

         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $parent.offset().top
         }, 500);
    });
})
```

Comment: yep this is something I'm really looking for, its working perfect except 'From 70's'.

Comment: If you read again the answer, you might find things suited your need. Just set the `maxHeight` to whatever height you want. I've updated my answer